# Easier way to handle missing values in categorical data in Python

Tags: r, python-3.x, missing-data, imputation

I'm trying to impute missing values in Python in a similar manner I can do using the "mice" package in R. This is because the manner of imputation I'm using in R does not require the data to be numeric, it can be categorical as well.

For example, I have a toy data set in R:

```
A <- c('M','F',NA,'M',NA,'F')
B <- c('Y','N','N','N',NA,'N')
C <- c(10, 4,8,7,11,8)
D <- c(0,1,0,1,1,0)
df <- data.frame(A,B,C,D)
```

I can easily impute these `NA` entries like this:

```
tempData <- mice(df,m=5,maxit=50,meth='cart',seed=500)
complete(tempData)
```

This method uses a CART i.e. decision tree imputation method. 
As far as I know, fancyimpute nor sklearn imputation packages can do this, can they? I cannot find anything on that.

Comment: I am not sure what you want to do with the imputed datasets. Using only one of the imputation sets is not advised. Rather use all of them to fit your model and then pool the estimates. https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/

Comment: @Wietze314 I know. I was looking for a manner of imputation in Python that does not require encoding the categorical variables first.